# Firebase push notification must open secondactivity

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to develop Push notification using FCM.I am able to get notification on my device and on clicking notification ,app opens MainActivity page(activity_main.xml) but it should open SecondActivity.java(second.xml) directly and also it must display notification message in Textview.
Here is my code-

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private static final String TAG="MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button BtnshowToken=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonshowtoken);
        BtnshowToken.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                Log.d(TAG,"Token: "+token);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }


}


MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseInsIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //get updated token
        String refreshedToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG,"New Token: "+refreshedToken);


    }
}


MyFirebaseMessagingService.java
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" +remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //Check if msg contains data
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: "+remoteMessage.getData());
        }


        //Check if msg contains notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message body: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

        //Display notification
private void  sendNotification(String body){

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //Set sound of notification
    Uri notificationsound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationsound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0/*Id of notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());



    }
}

SecondActivity.java
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    }
}


activity_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">





    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
        android:src="@drawable/firebase"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Token"
        android:id="@+id/buttonshowtoken"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


second.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"

        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc.firebasenoteg" >


    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Tell us what issues you have with your current code.

Comment: i am able to open my mainactivity page but when i click on notification its should open secondactivity page directly and also display  the message of notification in textview.This i what i want.Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to ClickListener from server request and add listener name in your manifest intent-action inside your activity.

```
"notification" : {
    "body" : "Body",
    "title" : "Titme",
    "icon" : "YourIcon"
    "click_action" : "YourActivity"
}

<activity
     android:name=".SecondActivity">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="YourActivity" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this is helpful, thanks

Comment: yes and same key which you have added in your push request from server side...both key are same otherwise it will not work

Comment: "notification" : {
    "body" : "Body",
    "title" : "Titme",
    "icon" : "YourIcon"
    "click_action" : "YourActivity"
} wat is use of this part?

Comment: I haven't put that in manifest.Your solution does work for me.There is one small issue that if i run my app and click back button so app is not running in background then later when i click on notification it takes me to mainpage and not second one.

Comment: its very simple, why are you confuse? you need to set clickaction in your payload server side and same action in your manifest...that's sheet.
Its also open your SecondActivity when app is kill..